# (Javascript/Wordpress) Show different content when checkbox is checked/unchecked

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm trying to show different divs with different tables(Wordpress shortcode) in them by checking and unchecking a checkbox on my Wordpress site. 
The code works fine on jsfiddle but on my website it doesn't happen anything when i use the checkbox. I want the div's to include different shortcodes. Maybe it has something to do with that?

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#overlay-1").change(function() {
$(".overlay-1").toggleClass("hide1337", this.unchecked)
$(".overlay-2").toggleClass("hide1338", this.unchecked)
}).change();

$("#overlay-1").change(function() {
$(".overlay-2").toggleClass("hide1337", this.unchecked)
$(".overlay-1").toggleClass("hide1338", this.unchecked)
}).change();


});
```

CSS

```
.hide1337 {
display: none;
}

.hide1338 {
display: show;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="nav">
 <input type="checkbox" name="overlay-1" id="overlay-1">  Checkbox  
 <br/>
 </div>
<div class="overlay-1">
<br>shortcode2</div>
<div class="overlay-2">
<br>shortcode2</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p6hFD/16/

Comment: Please post a [mcve] in your question showing us what the issue is. Also, have you checked the browser's console for errors?

Comment: I can't find any errors in the console that's related to this. What more information do you need?

Comment: If the code works fine in jsFiddle then that code alone is fine and there must be a conflict between that and WordPress. I believe WordPress uses `jQuery` instead of `$`. have you tried changing `$`? Also, how are you loading your jQuery in WordPress? In functions.php? A plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for Javascript here. Go with pure CSS making use of pseudo selector `:checked` and sibling selector `~`:

```css
.overlay-1, .overlay-2 {
  display: none;
}
#overlay-1:not(:checked) ~ .overlay-1 {
  display: block;
}
#overlay-1:checked ~ .overlay-2 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="overlay-1" id="overlay-1">  Checkbox  
<div class="overlay-1">
<br>shortcode1</div>
<div class="overlay-2">
<br>shortcode2</div>
```

Note: 
For this to work the checkbox and the content containers that you want to hide/show must have the same parent element and the content containers must come after the checkbox.

Comment: Thank you. Hmm, with this it doesn't show any of the divs either checked nor unchecked. Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Oh, missed the note... Now everything works just fine. Thank you!